# Can 'signature permissions' be used in an AVD on Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-automotive

I am looking to test Android permissions that marked as 'signature' in and AVD within Android Studio.

I have set up the key store & key and attempted to use/request signature permissions in my Android app.
I declare it AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.car.permission.CAR_MILEAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

and request the permission in `onGetTemplate` or on a button press

```
context.requestPermissions(listOf("android.car.permission.CAR_MILEAGE")) { granted, rejected ->
    println("$granted $rejected")
}
```

I expect a permission request to grant the permission but it rejects instead. This setup works fine for a 'dangerous' permission for example, which expectedly asks for a permission. The 'signature' permission fails silently.

I have also tried making a signed APK and using `adb` to send that to the AVD which also did nothing.

There is a possibility that the debug/release versions are getting confused but I have signed them both to be sure.

Documentation seems to just refer to uploading the the Play Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect a permission request to grant the permission but it rejects instead

`signature` permissions are not `dangerous` permissions. Only `dangerous` permissions get requested at runtime.

> I have also tried making a signed APK

It would have to be signed by the same signing key as signed whatever is being defended by the `signature` permission. In the case of a platform permission, that means your APK would have to be signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware that your AVD is running.

Comment: I see 'hw.device.hash2' with an MD5 hash in the AVD's properties. Other than that, nothing which looks like a key.

Comment: @Doot: You have to be the developer of the firmware. You sign that firmware as part of building the image to be deployed to devices (or, in this case, emulator images).

Comment: I see, thank you. So in my case, where I am using an AVD made through 'create device' -> 'clone device -> ...' is there some way to add it in? I am using Android Automotive and can't imagine that the builds available simply don't permit access to certain permissions on their AVD.

Comment: @Doot: "is there some way to add it in?" -- no. "can't imagine that the builds available simply don't permit access to certain permissions on their AVD" -- there is no requirement for a car manufacturer to let apps do anything that they want. `signature`-level permissions, especially those defined in the platform, are for the benefit of device manufacturers and trusted partners, not arbitrary developers.